# How to authorize a rails app to post to a user's account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, linkedin-api, sharing

I would like users of my_app to post to linkedin via my_app.

My_app will authenticate users based on email address, not LinkedIn.

What is the correct way to approach this?

I am thinking:

> 1. create user account (email based authentication with devise)
> 2. let user authenticate with linkedin and authorize my_app to post via their account
> 3. let user post items to linkedin via my_app

How can I achieve `#2`? Any code resources? I am finding a lot of solutions for linkedin-based authentication but that's not what I need.

I already have a linkedin app key am but not quite sure how to use it in this scenario.

Also, what gems should I use? Code examples would be very helpful

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate with linkedin use the following gem:

```
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2', '~> 0.1.5'
```

You are going to save the user's token:

```
auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
```

learn more about the authentication flow from their doc:
https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2

For Posting on Linkedin use the following gem:

```
gem 'linkedin-oauth2', '~> 0.1.1'
```

Then you can simply post by:

```
text = "I want to post this text"
linkedin = LinkedIn::Client.new(APP_ID,SECRET,token)
linkedin.add_share(:comment => text)
```